# Regular Expression writing for known pattern with dashes

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to write a regular expression for pattern matching for VB.NET. I need to have the Regex to look for a pattern like 12345-1234-12345-123, including the dashes. The numbers can be any variation. The value is stored as a varchar. Not sure how close or far my example is below. Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim testString As String = "12345-1234-12345-123"
    Dim testNumberWithDashesRegEx As Regex = New Regex("^\d{5}-d{4}-d{5}-\d{3}$")
    Dim regExMatch As Match = testNumberWithDashesRegEx.Match(testString)
    If regExMatch.Success Then
        Label1.Text = "There is a match."
    Else
        Label1.Text = "There is no match."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you had any problems, your pattern is correct ?

Comment: I actually haven't tested it, I was trying to find out if it looked correct.

Comment: Test it and see if there is any problem then post a question please.

Comment: Use a tool such as [this](http://regexpal.com/) to check your regular expressions. Or just run your program with a few inputs.

Comment: Hi @Sniffer, I created a test program, using the above code in my edited post, and I get the response of no match. So it does not appear the Regex is correct?

Comment: You've forgotten to escape the second and third "\d"

Comment: Yes that's the reason, you have forgotten to escape the `d`s so they are interpreted as literal `d` and not a digit.

Comment: Hi @Philipp, thanks, that's what the issue was.

Comment: Hi @BartvanNierop, thanks for the link to the tool, it's pretty useful and seems to work correctly. A good way to see if your regex works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down this regex:

`^\d{5}-d{4}-d{5}-\d{3}$`

- `^`: Match at start of target string
- `\d`: match character class of digits 0-9
- `-`: match dash (-) character
- `d`: match the letter "d"
- `{5}`: match the preceding class 5 times
- `$`: Match at the end of target string.

Everything looks good to me, except you should change your plain "d" to "\d":

`^\d{5}-\d{4}-\d{5}-\d{3}$`

Comment: Hi @pseudocoder, thanks, you found the problem. Thanks very much for the great explanation! I like the technique of breaking the regex down like you did to find the problem.